# Order by table using some part of string mysql

Tags: mysql

I have column named as follows

```
artist_name
------------
Cora de Lang
test  a  nasde
saman  silva
```

I want to order by my table using last part of name I wrote some query but it does not work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `artist_info` 
WHERE status='yes' 
  AND display_on != 'asia' 
ORDER BY RIGHT (artist_name, LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(artist_name)) - 1) ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can use [`substring_index()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to pick the last part of name from your full name

```
SELECT * FROM `artist_info` 
WHERE status='yes' AND display_on != 'asia'
 ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(artist_name,' ',-1) ASC
```

[`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b004/1)